# How I can add admin css by username in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to add custom css for admin as below

```
    add_action('admin_head', 'hey_custom_admin_css');
    function hey_custom_admin_css() {
            global $current_user;
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();
            if(is_admin() && $user_id != '1'){
                echo "<style>#wpwrap{background-color:red;}</style>";
                }
    }
```

and working perfectly but I want to use it for username, not for user ID

Is it possible to have? If yes then please give me suggestions

Thanks

---

Edited code

1st... Css Working but for all users. Including which are listed in code.

```
<?php 
/** 
 * Plugin Name: My Plugin 
 * Plugin URI: https://google.com 
 * Description: Me 
 * Version: 1.0 
 * Author: Plugin 
 * Author URI: https://google.com 
 */ 
 
 
add_action('admin_head', 'hey_custom_admin_css');
function hey_custom_admin_css() {
global $current_user;  
wp_get_current_user(); 
$username = $current_user->user_login; 
if(is_admin() && ($username != 'xyz' || $username != 'abc')){ 

  echo " 
    <style> 
        #wpwrap{background-color:red;} 
    </style>"; 

 } }
```

Second... Giving error

```
<?php 
/** 
 * Plugin Name: My Plugin 
 * Plugin URI: https://google.com 
 * Description: Me 
 * Version: 1.0 
 * Author: Plugin 
 * Author URI: https://google.com 
 */ 
 
 
global $current_user;  
wp_get_current_user();  //Error on this line
$username = $current_user->user_login; 
if(is_admin() && ($username != 'xyz' || $username != 'abc')){ 

  echo " 
    <style> 
        #wpwrap{background-color:red;} 
    </style>"; 

 }
```

Given error for second

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in /home/dh_w4i633/site.com/wp-content/plugins/me/me.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /home/dh_w4i633/site.com/wp-settings.php(371): include_once() #1 /home/dh_w4i633/site.com/wp-config.php(106): require_once('/home/dh_w4i633...') #2 /home/dh_w4i633/site.com/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/dh_w4i633...') #3 /home/dh_w4i633/site.com/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/home/dh_w4i633...') #4 /home/dh_w4i633/site.com/wp-admin/plugins.php(10): require_once('/home/dh_w4i633...') #5 {main} thrown in /home/dh_w4i633/site.com/wp-content/plugins/me/me.php on line 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
  global $current_user; 
  wp_get_current_user();

  $username = $current_user->user_login;
  if(is_admin() && ($username == 'username' || $username == 'another_username')){

      echo "<style>#wpwrap{background-color:red;}</style>";

  }
?>
```

Edit:

The second code in your edit is giving you an error since you're running it at all times instead of attaching it to a hook, hence the error.

Your first code in your edit seems to be correct, so let us stick with that. The reason it is changing the css for all users including your unwanted users is because of the OR `||` operator. You'll want to replace it with the AND `&&` operator. Your condition will become:

`if(is_admin() && $username != 'xyz' && $username != 'abc')`

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot,.. Working perfectly... Just one thing, can I add more than one username?

Comment: Yep, one way to do it is to add another condition as shown above in my edit.

Comment: Hi Haidousm
I created plugin as bleow and getting error at line 13. Any idea? In function.php it is working perfectly.

<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: MyPlugin
 * Plugin URI: https://google.com
 * Description: m
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: g
 * Author URI: https://google.com
 */


  global $current_user; 
  wp_get_current_user();

  $username = $current_user->user_login;
  if(is_admin() && ($username == 'username' || $username == 'another_username')){

      echo "<style>#wpwrap{background-color:red;}</style>";

  }

Comment: Sorry, I just added add_action('admin_head', 'hey_custom_admin_css');

function hey_custom_admin_css() { in starting and it worked for single username but not working for than one username in plugin...

Comment: can you post your new full code? please format it correctly

Comment: Hi.... I tried my best to put code here but not working at all. Full code is going in single line. I have upload it on easy upload. Here is link https://easyupload.io/ngnkb5 ... Thanks a lot @haidousm

Comment: You might want to try and edit your initial post to include the code next time. You'll rarely find people willing to download files. Anyways, I think you missed the parenthesis on the second condition. It should be like so:  
`if(is_admin() && ($username == 'username' || $username == 'another_username'))`

You have it as:

`if(is_admin() && $username == 'username' || $username == 'another_username')`

Comment: Hi... Thanks a lot again for your support. Again have same issue. Line 13... Code at line 13 is  wp_get_current_user(); ....

Comment: Can you add your new code to your initial post as an edit? Could you also add along with it the error?

Comment: Hi.. I edited real post :D Please have a look. I have put both type of codes I am used. Thank you sooooooooo much @haidousm

Comment: Worked perfectly... Thank you soooooooooooo much.. I don't know how I thank you. I am not getting words. Thanks a lot from bottom of my heart. Thank you soooo soooo sooo much... Thanks again :D